# How is (uint) index >= (uint)_size better than index >= _size?

Tags: c#, .net, vector, data-structures, dynamic-arrays

I looked under the hood of `List<T>` and came across the following piece of code:

```
public T this[int index] {
        get {
            // Following trick can reduce the range check by one
            if ((uint) index >= (uint)_size) {
                ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
            Contract.EndContractBlock();
            return _items[index]; 
        }

        set {
            if ((uint) index >= (uint)_size) {
                ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
            Contract.EndContractBlock();
            _items[index] = value;
            _version++;
        }
    }
```

In both `if` statements, `index` and `_size` (of type `Int32`) are casted to `UInt32`, <s>I know it is not because of overflow, because first `if` has a comment stating otherwise</s>.

**Question:** *What is this concept of casting integer to unsigned-integers other than overflow, and in what specific situation can it be useful to a developer?*

Comment: Think about this: is `(uint)-1 >= (uint)_size`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is to handle both negative numbers and positive numbers in one step.

If you cast a negative numbers to `uint`, the result is guaranteed to be larger than than `int.MaxValue`. So any negative index will fail the `(uint) index >= (uint)_size` check. If you remove the  cast you would need to do two checks: `index < 0 || index >= _size`. Since the cast is "free" this end up improving performance a bit.

Comment: So basically this casting helped us in combining 2 `if` statements into 1, and thus reducing branching in the method, correct?

Comment: @phougatv yes. that is the basic idea. But keep in mind that the jitter and/or CPU will apply optimizations, so the two check solution might not actually result in two individual, expensive, branches.